# Send Image from android to Node.js using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, asynchttpclient

I'd like to send image from android app to node.js server to save into MongoDB on server side. I use `AsyncHttpClient` to post request.

My code is like this:

Android ->

```
RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
param.put("email", email);
param.put("image", file, "image/jpg");

System.out.println("Param : " + param);
HttpClient.post("uploadImg_Profile/", param, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

Node.js ->

```
app.js->
app.post('/uploadImg_Profile/', function(req, res){
    uploadImg_Profile.uploadImg_Profile(req, res);
})

uploadImg_Profile.js->

exports.uploadImg_Profile= function(req, res){
    var User = new user({ 
        email : req.body.email,
        img : req.body.image
    });
    //
    console.log("req : " + req);

    console.log("email : "+ User.email);
    console.log("image : " + User.img);
```

But console.log result is undefined. I respect that this is seen *jhgdsfejdi734634jdhfdf* like this BSON type result.

1. How can I get img data?
2. There is a way to get file's type from File object dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the right type of body parser in your node.js code - from the result you are getting, it looks as if you're not interpreting it as a multipart form.

You need to register the middleware to use to interpret the POST, for example, using the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) parser:

app.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(multer({ inMemory: true, putSingleFilesInArray: true }));

app.post('/uploadImg_Profile/', function(req, res){
    uploadImg_Profile.uploadImg_Profile(req, res);
});
```

uploadImg_Profile.js:

```
exports.uploadImg_Profile= function(req, res){
    var User = new user({ 
        email : req.body.email,
        img : req.files['image'][0].buffer
    });

    console.log("req : " + req);

    console.log("email : "+ User.email);
    console.log("image : " + User.img);
}
```

Multer will also populate various other properties about the file, so you should be able to retrieve the type of the image from that using:

```
req.files['image'][0].mimetype
```

See the [multer page on github](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for all the goodness.

**EDIT**: Added bodyparser.json as well as multer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.
I used multer before another project.
Did you mean user multer instead of express.bodyparser?
When I get rid of app.use(express.bodyparser) and use app.use(multer(~~~)), It send a message that

Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Please keep helping me....

Comment: @YoungHoonKim yes, I believe the standard bodyparser can't do multipart form support so won't be able to interpret your file. You can choose for each route whether to use bodyparser or multer by passing the appropriate one - I'll add a second example to the answer to clarify using both.

Comment: Thanks for your added comment. Refer to your previous comment, I fix my code like below.

and I get the same result. img output is undefined.

var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({
    inMemory: true,
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename;
    }
}));

exports.uploadImg_Profile= function(req, res){
 var User = new user({ 
  email : req.body.email,
  img : req.files['image']
 });
 //
 console.log("req : " + req);
 
 console.log("email : "+ User.email);
 console.log("image : " + User.img);

Comment: And when I use req.files['image'][0].buffer, 
Error fired, TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Comment: When I fix like your example,

app.post('/uploadImg_Profile/', multer({inMemory: true, putSingleFilesInArray: true}), function(req, res){
 uploadImg_Profile.uploadImg_Profile(req, res);
})

this post function dosen't grap android request. uploadImg_profile function dosen't call. It mean that this request dosen't include multipart form data?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a more complete copy of your node.js code? I'm struggling to understand the syntax you're using there.

Comment: @YoungHoonKim Updated - try that now?

Comment: I don't know what is different your answer from my code~ T_T

Comment: I'm passing multer on app.post in app.js instead of requiring it in uploadimage_profile.js, that should make it specific to this route. What is the outcome with the code as I've given in this answer? do you get a valid HTTP request/response?

Comment: sorry, I tried your new answer and then, it can't take '/uploadImg_Profile' request. uploadImg_Profile(req, res) function isn't called. I can get email when it out from email output. I think that request/response is working from this result.

Comment: Can you update the original question again with your original code (before adding multer)? Before you changed it, it was receiving the request correctly (but not parsing the image), right?

Comment: Okay, I will try.
It is done. and this code works on email param. just dosen't works on image!
Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: @YoungHoonKim you're welcome, I'm curious as to why that doesn't work, but I've updated again - try that (change in app.js to just app.use multer, this will use it for all requests but it should hopefully work!).

Comment: Mark, Do you have hang out id? Its so long conversation.

Comment: When I do this, get rid of bodyparser and put multer, It can`t get email property. T_T... and I put both bodyparser and multer, can't read buffer..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then I'm afraid! Hopefully someone else can help - when using the express router, I have it working just fine with multer to process file uploads.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I'll keep finding and When I find core problem, I will make you know about this. thanks Mark. I have to test on simple project.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.
It is possible that both app.use(bodyparser) and app.use(multer) are used simultaneously.

app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(multer())

Like this.

And my previous problem is another points.
I don't know exactly what make it doing. I just change express version from 3.x to 4.x and test various situation. In this progress, I find out that req has image buffer properly, and can get buffer data.

Thanks Mark and all of you intereted in my question.

Comment: Great news - glad you've solved it. I've updated my answer to include the bodyparser.json so it covers the final solution to the problem.